# can't install Pop OS. Gparted not showing partitions from HDD

Tags: partition, system-installation, pop-os

I made a USB with Pop OS and I wanted to install it on my HDD because I already have Win10 on my SSD. All was good until I've had to select Modify partition it shows my HDD but with some error. But I don't want to format the entire drive because I've got lots of files.

Here's a picture of the disk layout:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't install any Linux distribution on a drive managed by Windows as a "Dynamic Disk", so you will need to convert Drive 0 to a Basic Disk. Since that's a Windows job and this is a Linux site, head over to [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) and search for "Change a Dynamic Disk Back to a Basic Disk", or [see these suggestions](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html).

May I be so bold as to suggest you back up your files before you do that, and verify the files in the backup match exactly what's on the source; then, backup-verify to a different destination? You've got lost of files, and I am sure you want that content to be safe.

Once Drive 0 is Basic, run the Pop! OS installer [following this tutorial](https://linoxide.com/distros/install-pop_os-system76/). When it gets to Installation Type, select **Something Else** and specify to install it to the second partition on Drive 0.